# Removing invisible points from a scatter plot (Manhattan plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, bioinformatics, seaborn

Consider a Manhattan plot for a genome-wide association study. [image: Manhattan plot example] The density of dots at the bottom of the plot is very high -- individual points are no longer visible. I'd like to skip plotting the points that completely overlap with other points (even though their x,y is not identical) to reduce the plotting time and the size of the exported PDF. Any recipes for achieving this? Collision detection? Subsampling?

I'd like to use matplotlib, though this requirement is optional. Ideally, the output should be visually identical to the "full" plot.

Some background info on the plot type:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_plot

Comment: By looking at the plot, I would say you can leave out all points with negative log P values smaller 2 and replace them with a bar. To reduce pdf size you may also opt for rasterizing the scatter plot. Concerning a possible solution I guess you would benefit from providing a [mcve] of the issue that would allow people to play with it.

Comment: You could also use a box/violoin plot and only include individual marker above a threshold. Or reduce the size of the individual points. If you provide a sample data set and code, you have a better chance of getting a more specific answer.